# go to other logical drives and continues to search for file

Tags: c++, for-loop

i have a program that search for files of a particular extention(.apk) in a particular logical drive(C:). my system has 3 more partitions :- D: E: F: and these also contains apk files. now i want that my program will also search in these logical drives for the apk's files. how i can do this. please anybody have some suggestion then help me, am trying this since morning. here is my code.....

```
int SearchDirectory(std::vector<std::string> &refvecFiles,
                    const std::string        &refcstrRootDirectory,
                    const std::string        &refcstrExtension,
                    bool                     bSearchSubdirectories = true)
{
    std::string     strFilePath;             // Filepath
    std::string     strPattern;              // Pattern
    std::string     strExtension;            // Extension
    HANDLE          hFile;                   // Handle to file
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FileInformation;         // File information


    strPattern = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\*.*";

    hFile = FindFirstFile(strPattern.c_str(), &FileInformation);
    if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if(FileInformation.cFileName[0] != '.')
            {
                strFilePath.erase();
                strFilePath = refcstrRootDirectory + "\\" + FileInformation.cFileName;

                if(FileInformation.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                {
                    if(bSearchSubdirectories)
                    {
                        // Search subdirectory
                        int iRC = SearchDirectory(refvecFiles,
                                                  strFilePath,
                                                  refcstrExtension,
                                                  bSearchSubdirectories);
                        if(iRC)
                            return iRC;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Check extension
                    strExtension = FileInformation.cFileName;
                    strExtension = strExtension.substr(strExtension.rfind(".") + 1);

                    if(strExtension == refcstrExtension)
                    {
                        // Save filename
                        refvecFiles.push_back(strFilePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        } while(FindNextFile(hFile, &FileInformation) == TRUE);

        // Close handle
        FindClose(hFile);

        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if(dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            return dwError;
    }

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int iRC = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> vecAPKFiles;
    //std::vector<std::string> vecTxtFiles;


    // Search 'c:' for '.apk' files including subdirectories
    iRC = SearchDirectory(vecAPKFiles, "c:", "apk");
    if(iRC)
    {
        std::cout << "Error " << iRC << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Print results
    for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator iterAvi = vecAPKFiles.begin();
            iterAvi != vecAPKFiles.end();
            ++iterAvi)
        std::cout << *iterAvi << std::endl;

    TCHAR szDrive[] = (" A:");
    DWORD uDriveMask = GetLogicalDrives();

    while(uDriveMask)
    {
        // Use the bitwise AND, 1â€"available, 0-not available
        if(uDriveMask & 1)
            printf("%s ", (const char *)szDrive);
        // increment, check next drive
        ++szDrive[1];
        // shift the bitmask binary right
        uDriveMask >>= 1;
    }
    printf("\n ");



    // Wait for keystroke
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Currently, you are using a do-while loop for that. Just out of curiosity, why it isn't good enough?

Comment: Didn't anyone tell you Systems Hungarian is hideous -- and useless in any language with an IDE that's worth a damn?  :P

Comment: @cHao There are still to many copies of Petzold out there...

Comment: can anyone from there, suggest me what i have to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a bit weird drive string `char szDrive[] = " A:";` (Even with the half-baked TCHAR stuff removed). I'd use `char szDrive[] = "A:\";` instead, and increment `++szDrive[0];`. You can then pass `szDrive` to `SearchDirectory()`

Comment: to pass szDrive to SearchDirectory(), first i have to store szDrive values in a array. and then by using a loop, pass array element to SearchDirectory()..  is am i right??

Comment: No, why would you? You don't need to store all drives in an array to print them. You can print `D:\ ` immediately, and for exactly the same reason you can search `D:\ ` immediately. Once you've completely searched `D:\ `, you return to the `while(uDriveMask)` loop and check if there's also an `E:\ `.

Comment: now i am going out of my mind.. working on this since morning.. @MSalters would you please explain a little more on what u answered